# Deriving log-level cofficients from level-level regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior

Suppose we have estimated parameters $\hat{\beta} = [\hat{\beta}_{0}, \hat{\beta}_{1}, \hat{\beta}_{2}]$ from a level-level regression:
$$\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_{0} + \hat{\beta}_{1}X_{1} + \hat{\beta}_{2}X_{2}$$
I want to use these estimates to set a prior on $\gamma_{1}$ in a Bayesian log-level regression:
$$\log(y) = \gamma_{0} + \gamma_{1}X_{1} + \gamma_{2}X_{2} + e$$

Is it possible to derive an expression for $\gamma_{1}$ from the $\hat{\beta}$s?

Comment: I think the first part [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243463/7071) is what you have in mind.

Comment: The log example is covered [here](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/dummies-for-dummies.html).

Comment: So gamma_1 = dy/dx * 1/mean(y_hat) = beta_1 / mean(y_hat)?

Comment: It won't be exact, only approximate.

Comment: Where does the approximation error come from?

Comment: The non-linear transformation from the log.

Comment: Would be nice to see the derivation!