Linear regression: interpret coefficient in terms of percentage change when the outcome variable is a count number
I have a linear regression, where Y is a count number.
Y = a + b1X1 + b2X2

I know we can interpret b1 as: a unit increase in X1 will change Y by b1. But how can I interpret it in terms of percentage? I understand I can use Poisson when Y is a count number. But just given the linear regression, is there a way to interpret b1 in percentage value?

No. You cannot interpret b1 as a percentage. To simplify things say X2 = 0. Take two differences Y(X1=2) - Y(X1=1) = b1 and Y(X1=21) - Y(X1=20) = b1. Both (expected) differences are equal to b1. Then consider the percent change b1 /(a + b1) vs b1 / (a + 20b1).

@dipetkov  That seems like an answer to me.

You could transform your OLS coefficient into an (semi)elasticity: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243463/7071

You can't interpret the coeficcients of your current model as percentage change, but you would be able if you take the logarithm of your response before fitting your model. In the model log(Y)=a+b1X1+b2X2 you can interpret coefficients as (proportional to) percentage change.

No, you cannot interpret $b_1$ as a percentage.
To simplify the argument, say $X_2 = 0$. (Any fixed value for $X_2$ will do.) In this case, the regression equation becomes $Y = a + b_1X_1$.
Let's look at $Y$ when $X_1 = 1$ vs $X_1 = 2$. That's a difference of one unit of $X_1$ and the expected difference in $Y$ is $(a + 2b_1) - (a + b_1) = b_1$ units of $Y$.
Similarly, if we compare the outcome when $X_1 = 20$ vs $X_1 = 21$: one unit difference in $X_1$ corresponds to $b_1$ units difference in $Y$: $(a + 21b_1) - (a + 20b_1) = b_1$.
What about the relative difference in these two cases?
In the first case, the relative difference is $b_1 / (a + b_1)$ while in the second case it's $b_1 / (a + 20b_1)$. If $a$ is small compared to $b_1$, we get about 1 and 1/20 respectively. That's 100% vs 5% relative difference.
PS: It's a bit cumbersome to avoid the phrasing "a unit increase in X1 will change Y by b1". However, I think it's worth it as this formulation implies causality. It seems to say that we can affect a change in $Y$ by directly changing $X_1$. However (without extra assumptions) regression is a model of associations between predictors and outcome, not causal relationships. That is, regression lets us can compare subpopulations (of patients, students, etc.) Say the subpopulation of students who are 20 years old and those who are 21 years old, in terms of the average score on the GMAT test.

Causality? I would call Y=a+bX a model.

@RomkeBontekoe Better notation may help but I attempted an intuitive explanation. So regression is a model for E(Y | X = x): the expected outcome conditional on some properties which determine the subpopulations. In my students example, we compare E(GMAT | Age = 20) vs E(GMAT | Age = 21). This isn't changing anyone's age by 1 year. It's comparing students who have one 1 difference in age.

@dipetkov Nice explanation (+1). It made me wonder about this. If the independent variable is categorical, say gender, and it is the only variable in the model, proportional interpretation is possible. E.g. "the mean wage of men is 20% higher than the mean wage of women". That may be even more informative to compare across different countries than the difference in wages.

@BenP I didn't write that X is assumed to be continuous, thanks for pointing it out. The language of "unit change" seems awkward to apply to discrete predictors. On the other hand, with discrete variables we can designate one level, $x_0$, as reference which simplifies interpretation. Still, the $\beta_{x_1}$ coefficient is not a percent change ($x_1$ is a non-reference level); that would be $\beta_{x_1} / \beta_{x_0}$. (And it would take some work to get std. error for the ratio.)

@dipetkov I indeed interpreted the question of the OP a bit loosely or "interpretively". Funny that the statistic to be tested is then a ratio of two normals, quite difficult I guess. Thanks for explaining that

@BenP Through serendipity, the same -- or at least quite related -- topic came up yesterday on Andrew Gelman's blog: Report of average change from an Alzheimer’s drug: I don’t get the criticism here.

Thanks @dipetkov for pointing to this example!! Serendipity indeed. And sorry for my late responding.
